# Open subset and metric space intersections

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, metric-spaces

Suppose $(A, d)$ is a metric space. If $B \subseteq A$ is a subset and $O \subseteq A$ is an open subset, show that $O \cap \overline{B} \subseteq \overline{O \cap B}$ and $\overline{O \cap \overline{B}} = \overline{O \cap B}$. Deduce that if $O \cap B = \emptyset$ then $O \cap \overline{B} = \emptyset$.

I have an extremely long direct proof of this (2 pages) but I am looking for a shorter version. Does anyone have any short or alternative proofs of this? Any assistance much appreciated.

Comment: *Proof*: Let $x \in O \cap \overline B$. Then, in order to prove that $x \in \overline{O \cap B}$, take an open $U$ containing $x$, and keep in mind that we want to show that $U \cap (O \cap B) \neq \varnothing$. Now, since $U \cap O$ is an open set containing $x$, $$x \in \overline B \implies (U \cap O) \cap B \neq \varnothing.$$

Comment: @azif00 I see, thank you. How about the second proposition $\overline{O \cap \overline{B}} = \overline{O \cap B}$?

Comment: Use that $U \subseteq V \implies \overline U \subseteq \overline V$.

Comment: @azif00 If you put your proof formally as an answer, I can mark it as the accepted one.

Comment: That's right: the closure of a set is always closed, and a set is closed if and only if it is equals to its closure.

Comment: @azif00 But that only shows that $\overline{O \cap \overline{B}} \subseteq \overline{O \cap B}$. What about the other way $\overline{O \cap B} \subseteq \overline{O \cap \overline{B}}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Proof*: Let $x∈O∩\overline B$. Then, in order to prove that $x∈ \overline{O∩B}$, take an open $U$ containing $x$, and keep in mind that we want to show that $U∩(O∩B) \neq \varnothing$. Now, since $U∩O$ is an open set containing $x$, and $x∈ \overline B$, it follows that $(U∩O)∩B≠\varnothing.$
Next, the equality $$\overline{O \cap \overline{B}} = \overline{O \cap B}$$ follows by applying $U \subseteq V \implies \overline U \subseteq \overline V$ to the inclusions $O \cap \overline B \subseteq \overline{O \cap B}$ (which we previously proved) and $O \cap B \subseteq O \cap \overline B$ (this is trivial).

Comment: Is the last thing trivial because $B \subseteq \overline{B} \implies O \cap B \subseteq O \cap \overline{B}$?

Comment: @Kraftsman That's right.

Comment: @azif00 Would you mind briefly explaining why $U \cap (O \cap B) \neq \varnothing \implies x \in \overline{O \cap B}$? I'm new to analysis and this isn't obvious to me.

Comment: @Henry Sure! A point $x$ belongs to the closure of some set $C$ if *any* open set containing $x$ intersects $C$. So, since $U$ is an arbitrary open set containing $x$ that intersects $O \cap B$, it follows $x \in \overline{O \cap B}$.

Comment: @azif00 I understand, thank you!